# How to force a new property to be serialized in designer.cs

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-forms-designer

I added a new property to a component to uniquely identify every gridcontrol in my project, called GridIdentifier:

```
public class MyCustomGridControl : GridControl
{
    private string gridIdentifier = "empty";

    [Browsable(true)]
    [DefaultValue("empty")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public string GridIdentifier
    {
        get { return gridIdentifier; }
        set { gridIdentifier = value; }
    }

    public MyCustomGridControl()
    {
        if (this.gridIdentifier == "empty")
            this.gridIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

The problem is that for existing controls in my forms, the form only serializes the new property after I change something (read: anything) within the form. It might be the caption of the form, the size, etc.

But what I would like to see is that it detects that the form has changed when I open it, so I can save it and the new property gets serialized.

Does anyone have a clue why the new property doesn't get saved after opening the form and how to fix it? Any other ideas that help are of course also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess it is doing basic sanity checking (i.e. *should* anything have changed) - to prevent unexpected source code changes (I *hate* it when opening a file can cause side-effects - I'm looking at you, DBML!).

On a side note, to force serialization *generally* (I don't think it will apply due to the above):

```
public bool ShouldSerializeGridIdentifier() { return true; }
```

the `bool ShouldSerialize*()` and `void Reset*()` are a convention used by the framework.

Comment: Thank you for your reply: I've seen forms where unexpected source code changes in **designer** code happen due to newer controls. Regarding your side note: instead of ShouldSerialize*() and Reset*() you can also use the DefaultValueAttribute as described here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)